# fourier series by lebesgue integral

Tags: integration, fourier-series

hw:

anyone knows how to find fourier series over the function
$$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if $x$ is irrational}\\
0 & \text{if $x$ is rational}
\end{cases}
$$

by lebesgue integral?

Thank you a lot!

Comment: @zach:  You can use \begin {cases} \end {cases} for this.

Comment: @RossMillikan, oops, got it now. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Wouldn't it be the same as $f(x)=1$ since all the integrals would have the same value?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you meant to define this function on some finite interval, as Lebesgue integrals, $\int f(x)e^{ikx}dx$ and $\int e^{ikx}dx$ are equal since $f(x)=1$ almost everywhere (and therefore $f(x)e^{ixk}=e^{ikx}$ almost everywhere).

Comment: He seems to want the fourier series, so this is slightly off-topic. I've added another answer that explains the difference, hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 2):

First, since you asked for a fourier *series* expansion, not the fourier *transform*, you first have to establish that your function is periodic, and then determine it's period. Or at the very least, you'll have to simply *pick* an interval $[a,b]$, and simply pretend that $f$ corresponds to the periodic extension of $f|_{[a,b]}$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

Luckily, $f$ actually is periodic, since if $x$ is rational exactly if $x+d$ is rational for some rational $d$. You may thus pick any interval $[a,b]$ with $a,b \in \mathbb{Q}$. In the following I picked $[0,1]$ for, um, no reason at all other than us mathematicians love for those numbers. Well that, and it makes the formula slightly simpler.

Then just do the computation. You get $$
  c_n = \int\limits_{[0,1]} f(x) e^{-i2\pi n} \,d\lambda(x)
      = \int\limits_{[0,1] \setminus \mathbb{Q}} e^{-i2\pi n} \,d\lambda(x)
      \overset{\lambda(\mathbb{Q})=0}= \int\limits_{[0,1]} e^{-i2\pi n} \,d\lambda(x)
      = \begin{cases}
        1 &\text{if $n=0$} \\
        0 &\text{otherwise.}
      \end{cases}
$$

This if course is the same as the fourier series for the constant function $1$ on $[0,1]$. Had you asked for the fourier transform instead, the answer would depend on whether you're interested in a function or in a distribution as a result.

In the former case, the answer is that the fourier transform doesn't exist. For the fourier transform to exist, $\int_{\mathbb{R}} |f|\,d\lambda$ needs to exist, and in your case it doesn't.

In the latter case, then the result of the fourier transform of $f$ *does* exist as a distribution, in particular it's the distribution $\Delta_0 = g \to g(0)$. Or, if you want, the measure $\mu_0$ with $\mu_0(A) = 1$ exactly if $0 \in A$.

It still holds for all of these cases that there's no difference between asking for the fourier transform of $f$ and that of the constant function $1$.